# Magento 2 Migration Tool Error: Destination documents are not mapped: 0

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I used the Data Migration Tool 2.0.2 for Magento 2.0.4.

I started the command line:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data <source of config.xml>
```

and get the Error in Step **Log Step**:

```
Source documents are not mapped: log_visitor
Destination documents are not mapped: customer_visitor
```

So I added ignore tags for *customer_visitor* and *log_visitor* in **map-log.xml**:

```
<source>
    <document_rules>
        <rename>
            <document>log_visitor</document>
            <to>customer_visitor</to>
        </rename>
        <ignore>
            <document>log_visitor</document>
        </ignore>
    </document_rules>
    <field_rules>
        <ignore>
            <field>log_visitor.first_visit_at</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>log_visitor.last_url_id</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>log_visitor.store_id</field>
        </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</source>
<destination>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>log_visitor</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>customer_visitor</document>
        </ignore>
    </document_rules>
    <field_rules>
        <ignore>
            <field>customer_visitor.customer_id</field>
        </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</destination>
```

After this I still get the error in Step **Log Step**:

```
Destination documents are not mapped: 0
```

What I have to do?

Comment: If I deleted *<source><document_rules><ignore>log_visitor* in **map-log.xml** I get the error:

"Source documents are not mapped: log_visitor"

But no "Destination documents are not mapped: 0" anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: is there a reason you are not using the same data-migration tool as the magento install?

Answer (score 3):

If anybody else runs into this issue, make sure the `log_visitor, log_visitor_info, log_url, log_url_info` and `log_visitor_online` tables are in the source database. Since the `log_visitor` table grows to be Gigabytes in size, I've seen many database backups and migrations where those tables were left out.

The option could be to truncate these large tables in the **source database** *(especially if its an offline copy)* before migration:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE log_url;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor ;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_url_info ;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor_info;
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Thank you Gary

Comment: Just to add, even though you need all the log tables to be present, they can be _truncated_ in the source database before migrating.  This ensures the log step doesn't take hours for most likely less essential data.
`TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor` etc .  These tables should be safe : `log_url, log_url_info, log_visitor, log_visitor_info`

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely have to use the same exact data migration tool version as your magento2 version, that's probably your problem because I've never had to modify the map-log file.